# I want to initiate my activity anytime using Volume up/down hardware button is this possible using services?

Tags: android, service, onkeydown, android-hardware

I want to initiate my activity anytime using Volume up/down hardware button.
I tried in some links but no use.
And also i want to know how to use service for this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on Android. The Volume Buttons can't be monitored or accessed by your app unless it is the current foreground app (i.e. you have an Activity visible and in use on the screen).

An alternative could be to listen for device shake motion and start then.